# How to access remotely to elasticsearch 5?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I want to access remotely to my elasticsearch version 5.
I tried to add this line in the elasticseach.yml file as I did with elassticsearch version 4 (which worked):

```
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
```

However, it doesn't work and elasticsearch displays an error and does not work.

```
[sagemcom@localhost bin]$ ./elasticsearch
[2016-11-07T12:17:58,432][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
[2016-11-07T12:17:58,564][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [NqVMQ-B] using [1] data paths,        mounts     [[/home (/dev/mapper/centos-home)]], net usable_space [13.5gb], net total_space [23gb], spins? [possibly], types [xfs]
[2016-11-07T12:17:58,565][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [NqVMQ-B] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-11-07T12:17:58,574][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [NqVMQ-B] node name [NqVMQ-B] derived from node ID; set [node.name] to override
[2016-11-07T12:17:58,577][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [NqVMQ-B] version[5.0.0], pid[3400], build[253032b/2016-10-26T04:37:51.531Z], OS[Linux/3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64/amd64], JVM[Oracle   Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_73/25.73-b02]
[2016-11-07T12:17:59,776][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [NqVMQ-B] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2016-11-07T12:17:59,776][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [NqVMQ-B] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2016-11-07T12:17:59,776][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [NqVMQ-B] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2016-11-07T12:17:59,777][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [NqVMQ-B] loaded module [lang-groovy]
[2016-11-07T12:17:59,777][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [NqVMQ-B] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2016-11-07T12:17:59,777][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [NqVMQ-B] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2016-11-07T12:17:59,778][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [NqVMQ-B] loaded module [percolator]
[2016-11-07T12:17:59,779][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [NqVMQ-B] loaded module [reindex]
[2016-11-07T12:17:59,779][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [NqVMQ-B] loaded module [transport-netty3]
[2016-11-07T12:17:59,780][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [NqVMQ-B] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2016-11-07T12:17:59,781][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [NqVMQ-B] no plugins loaded
[2016-11-07T12:18:03,138][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [NqVMQ-B] initialized
[2016-11-07T12:18:03,139][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [NqVMQ-B] starting ...
[2016-11-07T12:18:03,349][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [NqVMQ-B] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
[2016-11-07T12:18:03,355][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapCheck     ] [NqVMQ-B] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
ERROR: bootstrap checks failed
max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process likely too low, increase to at least [65536]
max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] likely too low, increase to at least [262144]
[2016-11-07T12:18:03,364][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [NqVMQ-B] stopping ...
[2016-11-07T12:18:03,402][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [NqVMQ-B] stopped
[2016-11-07T12:18:03,402][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [NqVMQ-B] closing ...
[2016-11-07T12:18:03,417][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [NqVMQ-B] closed
```

Comment: The manual has advice on how to fix the max file descriptors/max vm area errors. You might want to take a look at those first, then check if the problem persists.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the link with the max file descriptors/max vm area errors... And which manual are you talking about ?

Comment: I was thinking of the [Elasticsearch Reference, chapter "Important system configuration"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/system-config.html).

Comment: I tried network.host: 0.0.0.0 but still doesn't work

Comment: Have you read the chapter and fixed the bootstrap errors yet? If so, maybe you can edit the question with the new startup log so that we can check if something looks strange.

Comment: I figured out how to solve that. I put http.host: IpAddr_ES. And it works !!

Comment: it works with http.host: myAddressIp

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error error says

***"ERROR: bootstrap checks failed
max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process likely too low, increase to at least [65536]
max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] likely too low, increase to at least [262144]
"***

Solve this issue as

**Development Mode:** If you are running elastic search in development mode we don't need to set the max_map_count. Just run as follows

> docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.4

**Production Mode:** : I f you run in production you need to set the property as below.

#### Linux

The vm.max_map_count setting should be set permanently in /etc/sysctl.conf:

> grep vm.max_map_count /etc/sysctl.conf
>
> vm.max_map_count=262144

**OR**

> sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144

Then Accessing it from remote is different case.